# Blazor generic component - unknown prop

Tags: c#, generics, components, blazor

this is my search metod in generic component:

```
 private ICollection<TItem> GetItems(string text)
{
    return DataToSearch.Where(x => x.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(text.ToUpper())).ToList();
}
```

I want change x.ToString() for TItem property, but i don't know how i can do it.

Should I pass anyone property name like component parameter?

Comment: TItem is a custom class

Comment: You can't do that with linq. You need to iterate all properties of 'DataToSearch' and get the properties same type with TItem and then compare the values. And you can't use ToUpper and Contains if your TItem doesn't contain String or IComparable  class

Comment: What is `DataToSearch`?  And where is `TItem` used?  You need to provide more complete information.